# google map react, from onGoogleApiLoaded apiIsLoaded doesn't called

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

Function apiIsLoaded doesn't get called, and map can't be initialized. What's wrong? When inspecting, I can see a div without a google map iframe, just empty space.
I need to apiIsLoaded be called, but cant find any way to do this. Here is the code, any help would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

const LocationMap = (props) => {
    const apiIsLoaded = (map, maps) => {
        if (map) {
            map.setOptions({ gestureHandling: 'greedy', mapTypeControl: false, minZoom: 2});
        }
    };
    const { address } = props;
    const center = address ? { lat: address.lat, lng: address.lon } : { lat: 0, lng: 0 };
    return (
        <div className="google-maps-wrapper">
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{
                    key: process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_KEY
                }}
                defaultZoom={address ? 8 : 2}
                center={[center.lat, center.lng]}
                defaultCenter={[0, 0]}
                yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
                onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiIsLoaded(map, maps)}>
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LocationMap;
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. When I use the package inside a CreateReactApp, it works fine. But when I try and use the package in my own app (which does not use CreateReactApp), it does not go into `onGoogleApiLoaded`. Maybe it is some Babel config. There are no console errors.

Comment: For me the problem was setting the initial `lat` and `lng` to null.  So maybe that is what `address.lat` and `address.lng` are being set to.

Answer (score 0):

check your method is calld by  GoogleMapReact or not

```
const apiIsLoaded = (map, maps) => {
      console.log('apiIsLoaded')
        if (map) {
            map.setOptions({ gestureHandling: 'greedy', mapTypeControl: false, minZoom: 2});
        }
    };
```

Second thing is you don't need to pass yes to

```
yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
```

change it to

```
 yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
```

Comment: let me know you are getting apiIsLoaded called or not or you can refer this https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react-examples/blob/master/src/examples/Main.js#L69 example

Comment: I have already checked, apiIsLoaded isn't called, and it's my main problem.

Comment: try this example https://codepen.io/maxrodkin/pen/WMyjXo.it might be problem with functional component refer this example which is class based so, first refer an example and try to convert it as classbased component might solve your problem

Comment: let's check step by step.first check your callback function works or not.like        onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => console.log('It works')}> .please check and let me know what happen

Comment: https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react-examples/blob/master/src/examples/Main.js#L69